# Cannot see controlls of presented view that I dragged on stroyboard after calling presentModalViewController

Tags: ios

I am a newbie in iOS developing. I am trying to accomplish a sample from a book, but I use storyboard instead of xib. I added some buttons to one of the view and assigned a viewcontroller to it. I tried to call presentModalViewController to show the view in a action, but it seems nothing on the presented view. I add some code in viewdidload, and it works. But why can I see the buttons that on storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, rather than instantiating and presenting the view controller yourself. Only then is it deserialized from the storyboard.

If you really want to just use the storyboard as a holding area for your transitions, deserialize it with `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"whatever"]` and present the result. But that's not how storyboards are intended to work; the intent is to specify both the destination and the transition in your segue. That it's presented as a modal is just a part of the segue you define.

Think of it this way: A storyboard is not a direct replacement for a XIB. A XIB defines a single view controller's contents. A storyboard not only defines many view controllers and their contents, but how the view controllers interact with each other.